# Find all integer solutions of the equation $y^3=x^3+8x^2-6x+8$

Tags: calculus, number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find all integer solutions of the equation $$y^3=x^3+8x^2-6x+8$$

I tried to factorize the expression but I couldn't find any. Also, $x=0$ is a trivial solution. Also, I calculated it's local minima and extrema but I doubt that it's of any help.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *MathStackExchange is very bad*? I beg to differ

Comment: This has been asked many times here, see for example also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1436320/solve-y3-x38x2-6x8-for-positive-integers-x-y?noredirect=1&lq=1). So Math Stackexchange is too good. It already knows the standard questions.

Comment: @FShrike it is...it suspends accounts without having any justification

Comment: There is always a clear justification in my experience!

Comment: At least there have been some very offensive actions, of which some of them resulted in an account suspension. This doesn't imply that all account suspensions are of this type, I have to admit. But as usual, both sides need to be heard then.

Comment: @DietrichBurde they also don't respond to replies